# Why am I not able to untick this checkbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My ASP code is as follows:

```html
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" Checked="false"/>
```

And in my JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('chk').checked = result.isUserSpecific;
    if (result.isUserSpecific === 'False') {
        document.getElementById('chkUserSpecific').checked = 'False';
    }
```

I'm currently able to tick the checkbox through JavaScript when the result is `true` but I can't seem to untick the box.

I've tried changing `'False'` to `'false'` and it appears that the result being returned is definitely False. Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Look at the HTML, not the ASP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a boolean value to the `checked` property, not a string.

`false` or `true` not `'False'` and not `'false'`.

`'false'` and `'False'` are both true values when coerced into a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET ensures HTML `id` attributes are unique on its controls by prefixing them. What you're declaring as `chk` is being converted to something like `c100_c100_chk` before being added to your page.

The easiest way to support this would be to use `document.querySelector()`, passing in an attribute selector which matches the end of your element's ID:

```
document.querySelector('[id$="chk"]').checked = ...;
```

Furthermore, the string value 'False' is a *truthy* value and will evaluate to `true`. You need to set this to `false`, not `'False'`:

```
document.getElementById('chkUserSpecific').checked = false;
```